# How to define and (de)serialize an IPAddress in protobuf / C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, ip-address

```
public class Example
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IPAddress Ip { get; set; }
    public string ExampleDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the `.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Register {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp Date = 1;
    ??? Ip = 2;
    string ExampleDescription = 3;
}
```

I would like to send the above example message from client <-> server over UDP using Protobuf and I'm not sure how I would handle an IPAddress correctly. I could serialize it as string (which would probably improve interop with other languages) but I've also seen a `.proto` like:

```
oneof ip_addr {
    fixed32 v4 = 1;
    bytes v6 = 2;
}
```

I would prefer to keep my (above 'example') class intact. I also need to support both IPv4 and IPv6. I prefer small, optimal, messages and (de)serialization since I'm processing many thousands p/sec and I expect that number to go up in the future.

Either way ((de)serializing as string or using the `oneof` method), I'll need to implement my own custom (de)serializer for this? What would be the best way to go about that or does anyone have a pointer to a good tutorial/documentation on how to implement this in C#?

Also in the future I might want to use an `IpEndpoint`; I would probably re-use the "ip proto" and stick an `int32 Port` on it?

Comment: It uses an http connection.  HTTP can either use the machine name https:\\servername or IP https\\IP.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng are you sure you're answering the right question? this is about serializing the `IPAddress` type, not gRPC

Answer (score 1):

Edit: with API additions in v3, there are now 3 different ways to achieve this; they are all documented [here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/Examples/Issues/SO64101495.cs).

---

- If you are using the Google serializer; that just won't work - you'll need a dedicated POCO for serialization that uses protobuf primitives - presumably `string`.
- If you are using protobuf-net, `AllowParseableTypes` is your friend; see [this example](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/7519b44f8c1c181ac48f0fa986a64725a6f95cdd). I also paste it here in order to be easier for you to find it.

```
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using System;
using System.Net;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace ProtoBuf.Issues
{
    public class SO64101495
    {
        public SO64101495(ITestOutputHelper log)
            => Log = log;
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper Log;
        [Fact]
        public void RoundTripIPAddess()
        {
            var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
            model.AllowParseableTypes = true;

            var schema = model.GetSchema(typeof(Example));
            Log?.WriteLine(schema);
            Assert.Equal(@"syntax = ""proto3"";
package ProtoBuf.Issues;
import ""google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"";
message Example {
   .google.protobuf.Timestamp Date = 1;
   string Ip = 2;
   string ExampleDescription = 3;
}
", schema);
        }



        [ProtoContract]
        [CompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Level300)] // use timestamp.proto for Date
        public class Example
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(2)]
            public IPAddress Ip { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(3)]
            public string ExampleDescription { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

There's also an upcoming change in Ver3 that should make this more extensible. 
This new feature could potentially work well with your `oneof ip_addr` approach, but it would need a dummy wrapper type. I can expand on that idea more if it is of your interest.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Where would I find documentation on `AllowParseableTypes` and how does it work exactly? If I were serializing to Json (using System.Text.Json for example) I'd implement a `JsonConverter<IPAddress>` and pass it to the serializer using `JsonSerializerOptions`; ideally such an approach (or similar) would be used for protobuf-net. I would love to learn more so if you would like to expand: please do!

Comment: Hmm, I just learned about "Surrogate serialization", maybe that is closer to what I was expecting. Looking into that as we speak; maybe it's a good fit, maybe not. Not sure yet.
Also - to answer your first question - I *am* using the Google serializer but willing to switch to protobuf-net.

Comment: @RobIII `AllowParseableTypes` simply looks for types that have a static `Parse` method, using that and `ToString()` - it is very simplistic; the surrogate approach is probably more relevant - it allows complex types to be registered with your own conversion logic. Note that the changes to make this API more friendly in v3 aren't quite "baked" yet, which is why the commit above is in a branch, not the main/trunk, but there's nothing really stopping me merging it. Oddly enough, when I tried to use the surrogate API here (rather than the global flag) it didn't like it - I'll find what that was.